# What language is the generated Makefile.in written in?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, automake

Here is what I think I know (please correct me if I'm wrong):
configure.ac --- macros
Makefile.am --- variable definitions
configure  --- shell script
Makefile   --- makefile's own syntax

Despite scanning gnu documentation on automake , I couldn't find out, written in plain words, what language the Makefile.in generated by automake is written in. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Makefile.in` files generated by Automake are templates for the Makefiles that are ultimately to be generated at build time when `configure` is run.<sup>*</sup>  As such, they are mostly written in `make`'s language -- they are very similar to the Makefiles generated from them -- but they allow for, and in practice, they always contain, several tokens for `configure` to replace with values that it chooses.

To the extent that you want to consider the language in which `Makefile.in` files are written to be distinct from `make`'s language, it is an unnamed custom template language specific to the Autotools.  From that perspective, it is by no means limited to `Makefile`s, and only because of their role do `Makefile.in` files happen to so resemble `Makefile`s.

---

<sup>*</sup>Technically, `configure` writes another shell script, `config.status`, that performs the actual template processing.

Comment: Thanks a bundle --- exactly the answer I was looking for !